# Angular FormArray does not update in template

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component that defines a form consisting of one `FormArray`, defined as such:

```
form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  searchCriteria: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      field: ['', Validators.required],
      value: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  ])
});
```

Within this component, I have the following methods:

```
get criteriaArray(): FormArray { return this.form.get('searchCriteria') as FormArray; }

addCriteria(index: number): void {
  this.criteriaArray.push(
    this.fb.group({
      field: ['', Validators.required],
      value: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  );
}

setCriteria(index: number, field: string, value: string): void {
  this.criteriaArray.at(index).get('field')?.setValue(field);
  this.criteriaArray.at(index).get('value')?.setValue(value);
}

setValue(query: Array<Array<string>>): void {
  query.forEach((value, index) => {
    this.setCriteria(index, query[index][0], query[index][1]);

    if (index !== query.length - 1) {
      this.addCriteria(index);
    }
  }
}
```

Template is defined as:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="searchCriteria">
    <div *ngFor="let criteria of criteriaArray.controls; let criteriaIndex=index" [formGroupName]="criteriaIndex">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Field</mat-label>
        <input [formControl]="field" matInput>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
        <input [formControl]="value" matInput>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When calling `setValue` from a parent component with the argument `[['genus', 'test-genus'], ['species','test-species']]`, the debugger shows that the `FormGroup` has been updated with the correct values (i.e., there are two objects in the `FormArray`, one whose field is 'genus' and another's whose field is 'species'). However, in the UI, only the first object in the `FormArray` is shown correctly.

[image]

How do I get the second (or any subsequent) fields to display properly in the UI after calling `setValue`? I've been racking my brain for days on this... I have no clue why the UI does not reflect the data stored in the `FormArray`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that should be some like:

```
setValue(query: Array<Array<string>>): void {
  query.forEach((value, index) => {

    //If the formArray has not enougth space 
    if (index>this.criteriaArray.controls.length-1)
       this.addCriteria(index);

    //you can use "value" instead of query[index]
    this.setCriteria(index, value[0], value[1]);
 
      
  })
}
```